# AMI for EC2 instance with a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am running an Amazon EC2 instance with a MongoDB running on it. 
Since I will need to use it only for some time, I was wondering if it is possible to keep only image of the system for the usage time with Amazon Machine Image. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create an AMI from your server and then terminate the server when you don't need it.

When you need it again you can relaunch a new server based on the AMI you created.  The downside to this is that your latest data may not be up to date. So I recommend creating the AMI right before you terminate the server.

Another alternative is to just use EBS backed storage/instances and just shutdown the instance when you don't need it. You can just start the instance when you need it. There's little cost associated with keeping an EBS volume around. Certainly much less than keeping your EC2 instance running all the time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  In my case (a MongoDB on a linux) would you say EBS is a better option or AMI?

Comment: @Daniel I think it's better to go EBS

Answer (score 1):

A machine stopped it´s a machine that Amazon don´t charge you.

You get charged for:

Online time

Storage space (assumably you store the image on S3 [EBS])

Elastic IP addresses

Bandwidth

But Amazon charge you for your AMI´s created.

So you can stop your machine and just start it when you need to use it.